# Como enviar variáveis através de formulário de upload

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tentando enviar algumas variáveis que estão em um formulário de upload, as variáveis não estão sendo enviadas, já dei uma pesquisada aqui no SO eaté algumas perguntas, mas nada que pudesse me ajudar.
E nas buscas que fiz também não encontrei nada.
O que tenho é um form assim:

```html
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">     
   <fieldset>
   <legend>Informe o arquivo</legend>
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Escolher arquivo</label>
   <div class="col-md-10">
   <input name="userImage" type="file" class="btn btn-default" />      
   </div>
   </div>
   </fieldset>
   <div id="msgFoto" style="padding-top:10px;"></div>
   <div class="form-actions">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">      
   <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Importar </button>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" id="IdProcesso" value="<?php echo $IdProcesso; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="Mes" value="<?php echo $Mes; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="Ano" value="<?php echo $Ano; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="Operadora" value="<?php echo $Operadora; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" id="IdUsuarioLog" value="<?php echo $IdUsuarioLog; ?>">        
</form>
```

E o meu ajax, dessa forma:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit', (function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "pUploadImportacaoTelefoniaMovel.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {                   
                if (data.codigo == "1") {
                    $("#msgInsert").html('×AVISO!' + data.mensagem + '');                          
                } else {
                    $("#msgInsert").html('×ATENÇÃO! ' + data.mensagem + '');
                }                   
            },
            error: function() {
            $("#msgInsert").html('×ATENÇÃO! Ocorreu um erro ao inserir o arquivo. Contate o suporte técnico.');
            }
        });
    }));
});
```

Alguma dica de como contornar isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que os inputs hidden estão apenas com o atributo "id", e para que os valores sejam enviados na requisição é necessário que tenham o atributo "name".

Algo assim:

```
<form id="uploadForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal">                  
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Informe o arquivo</legend>
      <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Escolher arquivo</label>
         <div class="col-md-10">
            <input name="userImage" type="file" class="btn btn-default" />                      
         </div>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
   <div id="msgFoto" style="padding-top:10px;"></div>
   <div class="form-actions">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">                        
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> Importar </button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" name="IdProcesso" id="IdProcesso" value="<?php echo $IdProcesso; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="Mes" id="Mes" value="<?php echo $Mes; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="Ano" id="Ano" value="<?php echo $Ano; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="Operadora" id="Operadora" value="<?php echo $Operadora; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="IdUsuarioLog" id="IdUsuarioLog" value="<?php echo $IdUsuarioLog; ?>">                             
</form>
```

Comment: Fantástico @Diego Marques, agradeço pelo olhar atento, bem mais do que o meu.